# pods are not generating application logs continuosly

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have pods running in my production cluster. The pods suddenly stopped generating logs. When I restart the pod, it generates logs for sometime and again it stops. Can any one brief me what could be the issue?. I also notice docker container have logging drive size option(maxfiles and maxsize), how do we specify that in the deployment yaml file. Wil increasing the value do any help?. 
Specifying TTY=false option will help me in this case?

I have tried restarting the pod too.

Comment: If you do `kubectl describe po YOUR-POD`, do you see any `ephemeral-storage` specified?

Comment: No, there is no ephermal storage.